# WCF 4 Deployment Issue

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation

Am wondering what the following attributes in my wcf service xaml supposed to do.

```
sad:XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName ="My development machine wcf xaml location path"
```

1.Will it affect my service after deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That attribute is used to point to the workflow's XAML for debugging purposes.  If the attribute points to an invalid location or if the attribute is removed entirely, it won't cause any issues.  See:

[Can i remove the attribute：XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wfprerelease/thread/52cfebf6-cd1a-4698-8589-09a7d9921728)